# Missing values - Subset function

Tags: r, subset

## This code is not doing what I designed it for. Do you have any ideas why?

```
vet.in <- 1:30
vet.cut <- cut(vet.in, breaks = c(0,10,20, 30), labels = c("peq", "med", "gra") )

vet.cut <- subset(vet.cut, vet.cut == c("peq", "med"))
```

After the use of subset, elements with "gra" filled in desapear and the number of elements with "peq" and "med" are decreased to half, which is not the intention. The purpose of subset function is getting rid of "gra" while prevailing the "peq" and "med"

Comment: `vet.cut <- subset( vet.cut, vet.cut == "peq" | vet.cut=="med")`

Comment: It is not working because with `c("peq", med")` you are looking for a `peq` and the next should be a `med`, and iterating this across all you values in the vector. That is:  `vet.cut == c("peq", "med")` 
TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

Comment: Or simply `vet.cut <- subset( vet.cut, vet.cut!="gra")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you did not implement your intention - the code does something else.
If your intention is to filter out "gra", use:

```
evet.in <- 1:30
vet.cut <- cut(evet.in, breaks = c(0,10,20, 30), labels = c("peq", "med", "gra") )

vet.cut <- subset(vet.cut, vet.cut %in% c("peq", "med"))
```

The key to success is to use the %in% operator instead of the == operator.